# Load Freemarker Template from External Url

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, freemarker, template-engine

I have implemeted spring boot app where we need to send email using freemarker. 
App is going to deployed on google app engine, where file structure is not available to store the templates. So, I saved templates on google storage with public access. But not able to load in freemarker template engine.

```
freeMarkerConfiguration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/home/dnilesh/Downloads/helloworld-springboot/src/main/resources/"));

content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(
                freeMarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("Email.html"),model));
```

This above configuration will work on development env. But on Google app engine I dont have directory to store template.

I tried this :

```
freeMarkerConfiguration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("https://storage.googleapis.com/nixon-medical/"));

           content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(
                    freeMarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("Email.html"),model));
```

But freemarker not loading Template from External URL. How can I load this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For external URL,you should use [URLTemplateLoader](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html):

> If your template source accesses the templates through an URL, you needn't implement a TemplateLoader from scratch; you can choose to subclass freemarker.cache.URLTemplateLoader instead and just implement the URL getURL(String templateName) method.

See [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871713/freemarker-url-template-loader)

Answer (score 2):

Though there is an  accepted answer, I did not find the integration with spring boot. So I have done this

I was trying to read Freemarker template from google cloud storage with spring boot application.

So, I have done the following and it worked for me.

- Implement URLTemplateLoader and only override getURL method On
- FreeMarkerConfigurer bean, set pretemplate as custom template

CloudTemplateLoader - my custom loader

```
public class CloudTemplateLoader extends URLTemplateLoader {
private URL root;
public CloudTemplateLoader(URL root) {
    super();
    this.root = root;
}

@Override
protected URL getURL(String template) {
    try {
        return new URL(root,  "/" + template);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

FreeMarkerConfigurer Bean to set my custom loader

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() throws MalformedURLException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("localized_lookup", "false");
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(properties);
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setPreTemplateLoaders(new CloudTemplateLoader(new URL("https://storage.googleapis.com")));
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return freeMarkerConfigurer;
}
```

And my controller is following

```
@GetMapping
public String index() {
    return "<bucket-name>/index.ftl";
}
```

Don't forget to upload the template on the google cloud or s3. For test purpose, I added public access on my index.ftl file. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Thymeleaf resolver to load the external files.
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: Thanks, but in our project we are already implemented freemarker template